# How to clip/clamp/clutch/pinch side of faulty old LCD monitor screen?

Tags: substitute-tool, technology

[image]

Probably due to old age, the screen of my old Sony SDM M51 monitor flickers. The Sony representative advised that inside the lower left side (hereinafter abbreviated as LS) of the monitor (as depicted in red above), parts nearing the front of the screen have loosened from parts at the back. So  the only solution is to clench, grip, or squeeze the front and back of the red area (eg by hand), which has eliminated the flickers for the past years. Alas, the detachment worsened a few days ago, to the extent that my hands hurt and the LS now needs continual compression and grasp to stop flickering.

So what can I use to resolve this problem? I tried a large binder clip which only works when my hand clings to the clip; as soon as I stop holding onto the clip, it flings itself off because the LS is too thick.

Footnote: Please advise on apter words to describe this problem (I struggle to find the perfect diction). [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sony+sdm+m51&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jknrVJqmOY6wyATShYDoAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=744#imgdii=_&imgrc=AfDlkr0XEoVK8M%253A%3BIQbuHrwk8CCCHM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fpc.watch.impress.co.jp%252Fdocs%252Farticle%252F20000803%252Fsony.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fpc.watch.impress.co.jp%252Fdocs%252Farticle%252F20000803%252Fsony.htm%3B640%3B483) effected [the original image](http://pc.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/article/20000803/sony.jpg).

Comment: Why not take the monitor apart and see what needs to be pressed together? A little inspection would help. That way you know exactly what you're dealing with. Maybe a shim can be put inside allowing the body or case to hold it in place.

Comment: @dmcdivitt Thank you, but I'm only a tech amateur so hesitate to do this. Is it truly easy?

Comment: First unplug. LCD monitors do not have residual voltage risk like monitors with tubes. Pay attention so you can put everything back! Look for screws and take them out. Remove all screws found before trying to separate. Even if all screws are out there may be plastic catches still holding it together. When you take it apart, components will be secured by other screws inside. Do not stretch any wires. Find the spot where disfunctionality exists and see what to do. When putting back together, make sure wires are not trapped or squeezed by the case or shell.

Comment: @dmcdivitt +1. Thank you! Would you like me to post an aptly modified version of this question at SuperUser, so that you may respond there as a proper answer, for the benefit of others?

Comment: I did not know SU covered that. I thought it was software config. We aren't supposed to cross post. You should consider having this migrated, or delete this and do one there.

Comment: @dmcdivitt At least I think that it does. Anyhow, I posted this at http://superuser.com/questions/881725/how-to-fix-a-faulty-old-lcd-that-flickers. Please replicate your superlative comments above there, which I shall accept immediately. If I forgot for whatever reason, please remind me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adaption to the binder clips would be to put some adhesive putty on either side of the clip to hold it in place.
If you put something like ***[Blue Tac](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bostik-801103-Blu-Tack-Handy/dp/B0001OZI70)*** on either side then this will give it more to grip onto and it should keep it in place for your purpose!

There are always larger clamps and clips that you could buy in order to replace what you already have but in terms of working with what you have this solution is a goer.

A second possible solution which may or may not work is to ***stretch a few elastic bands over the side of the monitor*** (keep it on the plastic edges in order to keep screen un-obscured) this would probably work better if you had something underneath the bands in order to make them rise away from the screen and give it more of a pushing force to push the screen together, but again this may or may not work, worth a try though!

Thirdly and perhaps the most *'hacky'* method would be to improvise your own binder / clip. Get two sturdy bits of wood / metal / plastic, either as a rod or thin block type shape.

Three quarters of the way up the two rods / blocks *(hereinafter referred to as 'the rods')* place a wedge of paper (at least as thick, if not thicker, as the monitor) and then wrap an alastic band or two around the two rods above the wedge of paper (one loop below in order to keep the wedge in place) and wrap a few times until fairly tight and you can use them sort of like chopsticks.

You can then use them as you would a normal clip and add Blue Tac or something to the ends to make them more sticky if need be! Below is an image of chopsticks which is basically what I am trying to explain:

[image]

Obviously you'll need to to a bigger scale with a larger wedge in the middle but this is the premise I am aiming for, a couple of them may be better than one on its own.
Here is a link to how you can make these chopsticks [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YA8LltIwSYM).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any possible hacky solutions to this. I would use a spring clamp like either these:

[image]
[image]

They are large enough to grasp the monitor and (hopefully) not fly off. They are also usually inexpensive (< $2 USD).